# Receive signal from transmitter with PIC

Tags: arduino, pic, wireless

I have been trying to build a simple wireless setup using the parts enumerated in [this post](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/showthread.php?t=59142), except I am using a 16f88 pic. Like the poster in the forum I am able to send things from the PIC to the arduino, but unfortunately like the poster I am unable to receive signals from the arduino to the PIC. I have tried what he has done and I have made modifications as well, but I am still incapable of sending and receiving correctly. Right now my goal is to make a LED blink when the PIC gets a 1 from the arduino. I am relatively confident in how it is wired, but how would I make it so I can get good data?

EDIT: When running a program on the arduino to send a 1 every two seconds and a program on the pic to blink when there is a 1, it will flash sporadically and not follow any order. My guess is noise, but I doubt it considering how well the PIC to arduino program worked.

Comment: Do you get any data at all? If it's somewhat working but unreliable maybe some of the things I suggested here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/57547/picaxe-and-rfa001/57554#57554 are worth a try.

Comment: Do you have access to a scope? Probing on the TX/RX lines will help you see what the lines look like and how noisy they are. Also, double check that your baud rates are the same.

Comment: I do not have access to one. Baud rates are the same, both at 2400.

Comment: is it possible that your input pin is in analog mode? or used by another internal device, have you tried a different pin/port?

Comment: I have been using the Rx pin, which should be configured as a digital input pin. I will verify this in a few hours. Is it possible to receive such serial information over a different pin?